# Ignore special characters when creating a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, telnetlib

Is there a way to ignore special character meaning when creating a regular expression in python?  In other words, take the string "as is".

I am writing code that uses internally the `expect` method from a `Telnet` object, which only accepts regular expressions.  Therefore, the answer cannot be the obvious "use `==` instead of regular expression".

I tried this

```
import re

SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "\\.^$*+?{}[]|():"  # backslash must be placed first
def str_to_re(s):
  result = s
  for c in SPECIAL_CHARACTERS:
    result = result.replace(c,'\\'+c)
  return re.compile(result)

TEST = "Bob (laughing).  Do you know 1/2 equals 2/4 [reference]?"
re_bad = re.compile(TEST)
re_good = str_to_re(TEST)

print re_bad.match(TEST)
print re_good.match(TEST)
```

It works, since the first one does not recognize the string, and the second one does.  I looked at the options in the python documentation, and was not able to find a simpler way.  Or are there any cases my solution does not cover (I used python docs to build `SPECIAL_CHARACTERS`)?

P.S. The problem can apply to other libraries.  It does not apply to the `pexpect` library, because it provides the `expect_exact` method which solves this problem.  However, someone could want to specify a mix of strings (as is) and regular expressions.

Comment: `result = result.replace(c,'\\\\'+c)`

Comment: re.escape doesn't work?

Comment: add an `r` before the quotes, as in `raw_message = r'\try\this\raw\message'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `'reg'` is the regex, you gotta use a raw string as follows

```
pat = re.compile(r'reg')
```

If `reg` is a name bound to a regex `str`, use

```
reg = re.escape(reg)
pat = re.compile(reg)
```

Comment: The method `re.escape()` solves the problem.  I accepted your answer.